# I want to run App.js to show it, but it still shows only the code in index.js

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/1o1ly740pq

I am a complete beginner. I guess it 's a very rudimentary question. I'm sorry. I am studying react. 
I want to run App.js to show it, but it still shows only the code in index.js. Why?

Comment: Why does not the result say 'true'?

Comment: Let's not downvote the question asked. He might not know React today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not import and export the App.js file in index.js so App.js code is not rendering.
please find the updated code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/2xy029ol60

Comment: thanks for your kindness. react is hard ~  :) i will remember your code

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have made two components with name App.
The one you want to print as true, you have to import them in your new file.
check the https://codesandbox.io/s/xl0q1jkzyq

```
//index.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import App from "../src/App";
function App1() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Nice</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <App />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App1 />, rootElement);

//App.js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const text = "your smart?";
    const condition = "true";

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>react hi ~</h1>
        <h2>{text}</h2>

        {condition ? "true" : "false"}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I did not know that should not use APP at the same time. It has helped a lot. I will study harder.

Comment: Does the solution provided helped you? If yes, please show your love by an upvote. It motivates me to contribute to the community. :)

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/63ok3m8zz

You have to import App in index.js and put it in render()